# laravel: Where is the default validation in laravel Vue ui?

Tags: laravel

Would someone please point me to where to look to learn how to use/customise the validation functions used by `laravel Vue ui` in front end. I can't seem to find where the code for the validations for various forms. For example the email filed as shown bellow.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The error you are submitting is not from the backend. It is a generic browser validation, since it is an email type input.

However, to modify the form fields that are required when a new user registers with your application, or to customize how new users are stored into your database, you may modify the `RegisterController` class. This class is responsible for validating and creating new users of your application.

The `validator` method of the `RegisterController` contains the validation rules for new users of the application. You are free to modify this method as you wish.

The `create` method of the `RegisterController` is responsible for creating new App\User records in your database using the Eloquent ORM. You are free to modify this method according to the needs of your database.

```
/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

If you want to edit the validations on the frontend side you can look at all the views inside the `resources/views/auth` folder

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am actually interested in the front end stuff as I already created backend validation. I want to know how to recreate that pop up.

Comment: I have edited my answer to tell you where the frontend views are